# How can I access to specific items in python Dictionary?

Tags: python

I was trying to use google-api-python-client and I basically tried to access a view count of a youtube channel.

```
response = {'kind': 'youtube#channelListResponse', 'etag': 'ZTMivxEyhYPJqH2CZb0MvzTZ4ts', 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 1, 'resultsPerPage': 5}, 'items': [{'kind': 'youtube#channel', 'etag': 'Yxjey4KVgrhWSNhMTq1m1_52CJ0', 'id': 'UCCezIgC97PvUuR4_gbFUs5g', 'statistics': {'viewCount': '49964323', 'subscriberCount': '692000', 'hiddenSubscriberCount': False, 'videoCount': '230'}}]}
```

How can I access to viewCount value?

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = "(private)"

youtube = build('youtube', "v3", developerKey=api_key)

request = youtube.channels().list(
    part="statistics",
    forUsername="schafer5"
)
response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *this specific case* you can do the following:

```
response["items"][0]["statistics"]["viewCount"]
```

Comment: thanks! I searched a lot for the answer and could not find ;(

Comment: For the future: `["key"]` for dictionary keys, and `[index]` for list items.